# How do I use a self encrypting drive?

Tags: ssd, fde, self-encrypting-drive

I recently purchased a Micron RealSSD c400 self encrypting drive, and I am having a few issues when trying to get it recognized by my laptop (HP Elitebook 8440p running Windows 7 x64; also tried on a custom-built desktop).

When I try to initialize the drive from disk management, I get a CRC error; also, when attempting to partition it from Windows setup, the program can't create the partitions. I also tried with UBCD, nothing.

I assume this is due to drive security, but I haven't been able to find much information about this online; do I need a management software or something? I'm completely stumped here.

**EDIT**

As requested, when I try partitioning the device from Windows setup I get a 0x80300024 error; when I try initializing it from disk management, I get a "Data error (cyclic redundancy check)" message, and the event log shows the following under System:

Source: VDS Basic Provider, message: unexpected failure. error code 490@01010004 (2x)

Source: Virtual Disk Service, message: VDS fails to write boot code on a disk during clean operation. Error code: 80070001@02070008 (1x)

Source: Disk, message: The device \Device\Harddisk2\DR2 has a bad block (2x)

The security logs show nothing related. Also, when attempting to configure it from UBCD (utility: HDAT2), I get an error along the lines of "can't edit partition information" or something to that tune.

Comment: A CRC error usually implies an error in communcation. (e.g. due to a bad cable). It is quite difference from a 'permission denied' or a 'no acess' style error. 1) Please post the precise error. 2) Check cables (or in the case of microSATA, if the card is seated properly)

Comment: Thanks, added error messages to the post as suggested. As per the physical connections, I tried connecting it both via the builtin laptop connectors and from two different external hard disk cases; still no dice, although one of them doesn't recognize the drive at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that the unit is damaged. RMA'd.